# integrating facebook auth into my web form app

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I would like to allow my users to authorise my app with their fb on registration.

All of the examples i see redirect users to the fb canvas page after authorisation, but i only want this to be a step in the registration process.

Essentially, i want an icon they can click that would open up a new window where they can login to fb and a simple postback to the registration page where i would detect the login and hide the login button.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this using the facebook c# sdk?

Thanks and Merry Christmas :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do the same thing. I've got the CSMvcWebsite demo to work with my app, and it works as you desire (seperate window etc). I'm now trying to port it over to my webforms site, but it's not working yet.
You might try the same approach, and will hopefully have more luck.